# Solving recurrent function with 2 variables

Tags: recursion, variable-definitions, difference-equations

My understanding of Mathematica is very limited since I just started using it, I would appreciate any feed back or help.

I am trying to find the closed form of a recurrent function with 2 variables:

```
A[n_,k_] := 1/n*Sum[A[n-i, k-1], {i,1,n}];
A[0,1] :=0;
A[0,k_]:=0;
A[n_, 1] :=1/n;
```

I tried doing it using RSolve:

```
RSolve[{
a[n,k] == (1/n)*Sum[a[n-i, k-1], {i,1,n}], 
a[0,1]==0, 
a[0,k] ==0, 
a[n,1]==1/n}, 
a[n,k], {n, k}]
```

But i just get as a response the RSolve input:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVRX4.jpg

Am I doing the RSolve equation correctly or am I missing something out here?

Comment: Try this again in a fresh kernel; it seems you had old definitions hanging around.

Comment: Thanks for you reply! I tried that and now I don't get the recurrsion error. Although when i enter the RSolve, the output I get is the same RSolve formula again. Not the closed form.

Comment: It means `RSolve[]` has no idea what to do; sadly, for partial difference equations, this seems to be par for the course.

Comment: There goes my hope!
Thanks for the help though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this recurrent function have been researched before.
It can be solved by:
$$\frac{S(n,k)}{n!}$$
Where $S(n,k)$ is Sterling number of the first kind:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind
The Stirling numbers of the first kind have known generating functions and are much more researched.

@Sil deserves the credit for finding it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the recursion with seems to work

```
A[n_][k_] := 
  A[n][k] = If[k > 1, 1/n*Sum[A[n - i][k - 1], {i, 1, n}], 1/n];
A[0][1] := 0;
A[0][k_ /; k > 1] := 0;
```

I have tried with

```
A[5][1]
A[100][2]
```

which gives

1/5

and

360968703235711654233892612988250163157207/\
6972037522971247716453380893531230355680000

with

A[1000][5]

it's also working --- it gives 0.110791.

You can test or play with your recursion like this :

```
p = Table[N[A[500][i]], {i, 1, 20}]
q = Table[N[A[i][3]], {i, 1, 20}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried using the if clause inside the RSolve:
http://imgur.com/a/T1TMH
But got the same result. 
Is that were you were referring to? or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Sorry I have seen an error but to be able to correct It I must close my kernel and I cannot do it right now I will come back to this point later.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would really appreciate it!

Comment: I have corrected the code. It seems to work properly. But it will be advised to test manually for small values.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the corrected code. I can now play with the recursion, but I am looking for a **closed form** of the equation. You have any idea how to get to the closed from using the formula?  I think usually RSolve does it in Mathematica, but it doesn't seem to work for me.